# How can I add a tenant condition to Spring Data JPA Default and Dervied Queries

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Springboot Application with Repositories having Spring Data JPA Queries like findOne, findAll and also derived ones like findByID or findByName etc.

What I want to achieve is multitenancy. All entities have an "account_id" column which holds the tenant.

How do I add a filter like "account_id" to all the queries metioned above without using derived queries that contains those name slike findIdAndAccountid (which would be findone)

```java
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

    Category findByName(String name);

}
```

Here's the corresponding entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "unit")
@Data
public class Unit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private Long account_id;
}
```

I know most people use schemas as tenant separation but that's impossible for me. Is there a way (I didn't find one) to add such a tenant filter condition on those queries without writing NamedQueries or using DerivedQueries. An elegeant solution like annotate the repository or entity or maybe the queries that all queries should add the additional filter "account_id"?

Comment: Hi @Marc, please read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also shorten your problem, so It's easy for other to help you!

Comment: ok, I have re-read the how-to-ask and shortened the question a lot. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update and Solution**
1. Create a Filter & FilterDef on the entity like so

```
@FilterDef(name="accountFilter", parameters=@ParamDef( name="accountId", type="long" ) )
@Filters( {
        @Filter(name="accountFilter", condition=":accountId = account_id")
} )
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private Long account_id;
}
```

2. enable filtering in the controller by autowiring entitymanager, writing a method to enable the filter and activate the filter in @ModelAttribute for each request

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/categories",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public class CategoryController {
    private final CategoryRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    CategoryController(CategoryRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    private void activateFilter() {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        Filter filter = session.enableFilter("accountFilter");
        filter.setParameter("accountId", Long.valueOf(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant()));


    }
    @ModelAttribute
    public void initFilter() {
        activateFilter();
    }

    ... your rest methods here

}
```

Comment: On a side note - This approach only works for queries. When you try to access an entity through findById in the repo the underlying method uses 'find' with the id of the entity to fetch it instead of a query and ignoes the filter which would restrict access to entities no assigned to the tenant. One approach which worked for me was to create a custom Repository (interface + implementation) which extends JPARepository and in there overwrite the findById method. In my method I created a custom query which creates a query and so the filters are applied. Of course all repos must then use this repo

Comment: If you need to define a custom repo and create a query there, couldn't you just use query to begin with and define your where clause and avoid all of the above code?
`@Query("SELECT r FROM Records r WHERE u.tenantId= ?")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add Where clause on your Entity classes (Didnt had time to test )

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "unit")
@Data
@Where(clause = "account_id= :account_id")
public class Unit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private Long account_id;
}
```

Comment: Yes you can add `@where` clauses to entities, but I have not found a way to set the parameter when using derived qureise. All eamples with `@where` I could find use the EntityManager and then createquery. Can the `@Where` annotation be used with Sprint Data JPA and dervied quires? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @where clauses don't support variables. You have to use "Filter" & "FilterDef" see solution.